# Unable to connect to Tor using SOCKS 5

Tags: configuration, windows, socks, error

I am running Windows & want to connect to Tor using SOCKS 5. I have private proxies and when I tried any of them, all I am getting are these errors logs.

```
19/07/2015 02:31:24.671 [WARN] Could not create SOCKS args string. 
19/07/2015 02:31:24.671 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 199.254.238.52:443 
19/07/2015 02:31:24.736 [WARN] Could not create SOCKS args string. 
19/07/2015 02:31:24.736 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.175.225:443 
19/07/2015 02:31:28.452 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Not sure at all if this is correct, but shouldn't the Socks listener be set to something else beside **9150** (which is known as Tor Browser port?)

Comment: please post your torrc and full startup log for Tor - it's not clear what kind of problem do you have.